# Django FormView Response

Tags: python, django, httpresponse, formview

Hy! I created a new Django project to upload a photo using a FormView. The photo gets processed and a download link is provided. The problem is the response: I want the html page to stay the same, only the download link should be added.

```
class ColorImageView(FormView):
  template_name = 'images.html'
  form_class = ColorImageForm

  def form_valid(self, form):
    download_link = ....
    return HttpResponse(...?...)
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gF8D2.png)

Answer (score 1):

Just edit `images.html` with something like:

```
{% if download_link %}
  <a href="{{ download_link }}">Download</a>
{% endif %}
```

And pass the URL in the view:

```
def form_valid(self):
    download_link = ''
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(download_link=download_link))
```

Comment: What is the easiest way to show a progress bar while processing?

Comment: An alternative solution would be to use AJAX to submit the form and display the response (download link) on success.   
Check this link http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/upload-to-django-with-progress-bar-using-ajax-and-jquery/